# what is the error in this mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `p`.`id`, `p`.`propertyname`, `p`.`location`, `p`.`a_unit`, `p`.`t_unit`, pgi.img_name 
FROM `properties`  p,(select gallery_id from  property_addom as pa 
where  p.id=pa.p_id) as a join propert_gallery_images as pgi ON a.gallery_id=pgi.pg_id
```

when i execute it will show me the error

> `#1054` - Unknown column 'p.id' in 'where clause' and properties table contain id coloumn

Comment: propertyies  doesn't have id column in it

Comment: There are several problems with the query. The bigger issue is the problem with the question.  Please edit the question to (at the very least) describe the problem you are having.  Sample data and desired results are highly desirable.

Comment: In addition to what @GordonLinoff said, multiple English language errors in the query may cause errors if your actual DB tables use proper names.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of what you actually whant from this one. 
Maybe something more like this ?

```
 SELECT 
    `p`.`id`, 
    `p`.`propertyname`, 
    `p`.`location`, 
    `p`.`a_unit`, 
    `p`.`t_unit`, 
    pgi.img_name,
    a.gallery_id,
    FROM `propertyies`  p
    left join property_addom pa on pa.id=p.id
    left join propert_gallery_images pgi on p.gallery_id=pgi.pg_id
```